# How to change subpartition index initial size

Tags: oracle

Can I change index initial size in case there is subpartition table?
I get successfully changed the index initial size in case there is only partition table, without subpartition with the sql:

```
Alter index index_name rebuild partition partition_name storage(initial xxM) tablespace "DATA";
```

But I got ORA-14189 if I try to change the index initial size in case there is subpartition tables with the sql:

```
Alter index index_name rebuild subpartition subpartition_name storage(initial xxM) parallel;
```